# Enumerate the number of running processes with a given name - assign to variable

Tags: arrays, bash, ubuntu

I need to know how many processes are running for a specific task (e.g. number of Apache tomcats) and if it's 1, then print the PID. Otherwise print out a message.

I need this in a BASH script, now when I perform something like:

```
result=`ps aux | grep tomcat | awk '{print $2}' | wc -l`
```

The number of items is assigned to result. Hurrah! But I don't have the PID(s). However when I attempt to perform this as an intermediary step (without the wc), I encounter problems.  So if I do this:

```
result=`ps aux | grep tomcat | awk '{print $2}'`
```

Any attempts I make to modify the variable result just don't seem to work. I've tried set and tr (replace blanks with line-breaks), but I just cannot get the right result. Ideally I'd like the variable result to be an array with the PIDs as individual elements. Then I can see size, elements, easily.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?
Thanks,
Phil

**Update:**

I ended up using the following syntax:

```
pids=(`ps aux | grep "${searchStr}"| grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`)
number=${#pids[@]}
```

The key was putting the brackets around the back-ticked commands. Now the variable pids is an array and can be asked for length and elements.

Thanks to both choroba and Dimitre for their suggestions and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pids=($(
    ps -eo pid,command |
    sed -n '/[t]omcat/{s/^ *\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/;p}'
))
number=${#pids[@]}
```

`pids=( ... )` creates an array.
`$( ... )` returns its output as a string (similar to backquote).
Then, sed is called on the list of all the processes: for lines containing tomacat (the `[t]` prevents the sed itself from being included), only the pid is preserved and printed.

Comment: Hi. Can you explain the syntax of your first line?

Comment: The first ( starts an array definition. The $( is returning the output of its content as a string (similarly to `).

Comment: Explain the answer, don't just paste a snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to adjust the *pgrep* command (you may need or may not need the *-f* option).

```
_pids=( 
  $( pgrep -f tomcat )
  )

(( ${#_pids[@]} == 1 )) &&
  echo ${_pids[0]} ||
    echo message
```

If you want to print the number of *pids* (with a message):

```
_pids=(
  $( pgrep -f tomcat )
  )

(( ${#_pids[@]} == 1 )) &&
  echo ${_pids[0]} ||
    echo "${#_pids[@]} running"
```

It should be noted that the *pgrep* utility and the syntax used are not *standard*.

Comment: Hmmm. I've tried your first example and it does work, but I just don't get it. What does the syntax mean? I've also tried replacing pgrep with ps and grep but that just returns the wrong result.

Comment: Well, if you try to be more explicit? What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Could you try to describe the behavior you're getting?

Comment: Hi. Sorry, you've mis-read my comment. I said it does work but I don't understand the syntax - I was referring to the ( $(  ) ) syntax. I've looked into this and think I understand it further, BUT when I replace your pgrep with my own ps aux | grep ${searchStr} | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' I seem to get completely the wrong answer.

Comment: @Phil, sorry, I've misread your question. I saw you found a solution.